# How to use an image instead of an icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am currently doing something like this

```
new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_forward), text: "Browse"),
```

However I would like to use an image as an icon . I get images using

```
new Image.asset("assets/img/logo.png"),
```

My question is how can i use that image as an icon in my tab shown above ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As per documentation [Tab](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tab-class.html) icon property ask a widget so you can pass like this also or any other widget also

```
new Tab(icon: new Image.asset("assets/img/logo.png"), text: "Browse"),
```

Comment: Is there a way to style say with and height of the icon @RobinSinha

Comment: The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Icon?'.

Comment: SideMenuItem(
        priority: 0,
        title: 'Dashboard',
        onTap: (index, _) {
          sideMenu.changePage(index);
        },
        icon: new Image.asset("assets/img/logo.png"),
        badgeContent: const Text(
          '3',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),

Comment: what should i do?

Answer (score 25):

**ImageIcon widget is the most suitable widget to use images as icons in Flutter. You can use its property image to assign your own image.**

```
ImageIcon(
     AssetImage("images/icon.png"),
     color: Colors.red,
     size: 24,
),
```

Comment: This is useful on a BottomNavigationBar where the icon colour should automatically change when it`s active or not.

Comment: The argument type 'ImageIcon' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Icon?'.

Comment: SideMenuItem(
        priority: 0,
        title: 'Dashboard',
        onTap: (index, _) {
          sideMenu.changePage(index);
        },
        icon: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage("images/icon.png"),
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 24,
        ),
        badgeContent: const Text(
          '3',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),

Comment: what should i do?

Answer (score 7):

Most of the time you'll find that the underling `icon` property is a `Widget`, so you can directly replace your `Icon` with `Image.asset` and provide it a `width`, `height` and `fit` according to your needs:

```dart
Image.asset(
  'assets/images/foo.png',
  width: 44,
  height: 44,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
)
```

Example (in a `TabBar`)

```dart
TabBar(
  tabs: [
    Tab(
      text: 'Icon',
      icon: Icon(Icons.call), //    <-- Icon
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'Image',
      icon: Image.asset( //        <-- Image
        'assets/images/foo.png',
        height: 44,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 4):

So follow up to @RobinSinha answer, using the Tab widget looks weirds as the Tab widget has an external padding, so i'd suggest to avoid that:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
       icon: Image.asset(
           "assets/images/image.png",
            width: <put your desired width, recommended 24.0>,
            height: <put your desired width, recommended 24.0>,
           ),
        label: '<name for icon>'
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Little known fact. We can use PNG files in Flutter as an icon and change their color with color parameter like below:

```
 IconButton(
                        icon: ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage('assets/images/iconRandom.png'),
                          size: 30,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          // do something here
                        }),
```

So no need to create several different image files just for changing colors depending on condition. We can just change color of the PNG file.

Answer (score -1):

As @RobinSinha has said you can use Tab and then in for icon you can try the following

```
Tab(
        icon: Container(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage(
              'assets/logo.png',
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ),
      )
```